# Wordpress fancybox with iPhone fix

Tags: jquery, iphone, wordpress, fancybox

I am using wordpress and fancybox to show iframes and everything is working fine except on iphones.
The fancybox pops up but only shows part of the iframe, and doesn't allow you to scroll within it. I have tried to fix this using various methods, as suggested in stackoverflow and nothing worked. So finally I gave up.
So now I'm trying to get wordpress to detect and turn it off the fancybox when an iphone is detected though i'm having no joy with that either.

Does anyone know how to do this? If you have an answer could you mention where to put the code rather than 'just use this' with no indication of where to put it.
Thanks

Comment: If you gave up with the first issue, I bet you will give up with the second too because either solution would take the same amount of effort. I just wonder how come anybody can help you if you don't provide any code or link to the page with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to only initialise fancybox when the screen is larger than mobile.

For example, if you wanted to use fancybox for all devices above iPhone landscape, you would use the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($(window).width() > 480) {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    }

});
```

The logic behind the above code is that when the document is ready, we will check whether the window width is larger than 480px which is what iPhone landscape is, if larger than 480px, initialise fancybox.

I hope this helps. Good luck! =)

Comment: Just noticed that you asked where to put it. I assume it's pretty self explanatory because you're obviously already initialising fancybox in a script somewhere but I imagine you're not using the conditional statement that I've used. So, all you need to do is replace your fancybox init code in whichever script/template you've put it for the above code.